# getaddrinfo: start Temporary failure in name resolution Error opening specified endpoint "start" Server Exiting with code 1

Tags: fedora, net-snmp, snmpd

While starting snmpd I am getting this error in /var/snmpd.log

**

**> **getaddrinfo: start Temporary failure in name resolution Error opening
 specified endpoint "start" Server Exiting with code 1****

**
For your info m using Fedora-14 & net-snmp-5.7.1 .

Thanks in Advance..Help me

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error opening specified endpoint "start" Server Exiting with code 1
```

means some process is using `port 161`.

For example try `netstat -anp | grep 161`, then stop that process and start `snmpd` again.